Звідки пішло слово "ку" у вигляді привітання?
Існує думка, що це слово є спадком совєцького режиму, та почало використовуватися людьми через совєцький фільм "Кин-дза-дза", але інші люди вважають, що це скорочення від куку.
Чи є якісь докази, або логіка, яка б допомогла розібратися в цій темі?

Чи є якісь докази, що це є словникове слово, на яке мають розповсюджуватися «докази або логіка»?

у мене немає @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine
